# How to enable debugging mode in SAPUI5 library 1.40.7

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I was using 1.26.10. So I was executing

```
jQuery.sap.debug(true)
```

But When I do the same for library 1.40.7. It is not loading any dbg files

Answer (score 5):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to open UI5 Diagnostics. There you can expand the panel "Technical Information" and switch on the Option "Debug Sources".

Comment: I already try this. Still not working. Not able to Load dbg files

Comment: Did you do a reload after switching it on? And have you verified that it is still switched on?

Comment: I have reloaded, and I have verified that it is switched on.  But still not able to load

Answer (score 1):

See the official docu for this:
https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon20/helpdata/en/c9/b0f8cca852443f9b8d3bf8ba5626ab/content.htm

just add in the URL `sap-ui-debug=true` as query string `?....&...`

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and use Technical Information → Debug Sources is basically correct but there is one restriction which might prevents this.

The UI5 application needs to be initialized with `productive: false`

Check in your `index.html` if the `productive` parameter of `sap-ui-config` is set to `true` and change it temporarily to `false`:

```js
<script>
    window["sap-ui-config"] = { "productive": false };
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to add `window["sap-ui-config"] = { "productive": true };` to the `<script>`-section of the `index.html`, but it still loads `jquery-dbg.js`. I'm using SAPUI5 1.44.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, adding the query parameter `sap-ui-debug=true` in the URL would enable debug mode.

Adding ui5 namespace of your UI5 application in the query in place of the boolean `true` would only load files for that namespace to debug making page load faster. example: for namespace `foo.bar`, the query param should be `sap-ui-debug=foo/bar`